# No public constructor is available Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, unity-interception

I have inherited this project, I normally do not unity as my dependency resolver, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I am getting he following message when I try and resolve a interface.

Inner Exception 1:

> InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type
> [ProjectName].ITest

Inner Exception 2:

> InvalidRegistrationException: Exception of type
> 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown.

Now before anyone jumps on me and says I have no constructor the class looks like this... it has a constructor with no parameters.

```
namespace ProjectName
{
    public class Test : ITest
    {
        public Test()
        {
        }

        public int Foo() => 99;
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        int Foo();
    }
}
```

So there is a constructor that has no parameters
This is the class that is trying to resolve the class.

```
[Route("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    [Dependency]
    public ITest Test { get; set; }


    public TestController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        var i = Test.Foo();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing DI is set up wrong, `No public constructor is available for type [ProjectName].ITest` shounds like it is trying to instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 7):

The reason of exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type [ProjectName].ITest
```

is because the DI is trying to create a instance of a interface `ITest` instead of `Test`.

You must register the dependency to resolve to Test when ask for ITest, something like:

```
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to the constructor either. There should be a [new] Test.Foo() there. Or make Foo() static.